# How many subsets of $[n]$ where elements have a certain difference

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to find the number of subsets of $[n]$ where for each pair of elements in the subset $\{a_1,...,a_r\}$ it holds that $|a_j-a_i|>k$

I tried to generalize from the problem that no consecutive numbers are present in the subset, but this has failed in every way.

However, I suspect that this problem can be solved with a bijection to just usual subsets, but of $[l], l<n$ instead of $[n]$.

Comment: Recursive methods should work.  At least that should let you compute lots of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct:

If there are $r$ elements in the subset, then we can write the subsets (sorted) as
$$\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_r\}=\{b_1,b_2+k,b_3+2k,\ldots,b_r+(r-1)k\},$$
where the elements $b_i$ can range up to $n-(r-1)k$.

So the total number of possible subsets is $\sum_r \binom{n-rk+k}{r}$.